# Customise Vaadin CRUD Editor Width

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I would like to customise the dialog of a Vaadin CRUD component (java) by replacing the min-width of the overlay with :

```
:host([theme~="layout"]) [part="overlay"] {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

I put it into a css flle and then add in my java class :

```
@CssImport( value = "styles/gridCrudEditor.css", 
            themeFor = "vaadin-dialog-overlay", 
            id = "dialog-layout-overlay-theme")
```

**But it apply for all grid crud editor** and I would like to a**pply it to only one instance**.
By default, it's (in vaadin-dialog-layout-overlay-styles.js)

```
:host([theme~="layout"]) [part="overlay"] {
    max-width: 54em;
    min-width: 20em;
}
```

As it's the dialog of the crud... I don't how to proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

**Java**

```
crud.addThemeName("my-theme");
```

**CSS**

```
:host([theme~="my-theme"]) [part="overlay"] {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```